# Converting nested JSON to Java Object(An Interface having impl)

Tags: java

I am in need to convert nested JSON to Java Object which is an Interface.

Kindly refer the below example,that JSON string needs to convert into Java Object of type Root.

JSON: `{"ROOT":{"NAME":"EVEN"}}`

Java:

```
Interface Root {
    String getName();
}

class RootImpl implements Root{
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Like the below usecase i need to convert nested json of large depth to Java Object.

Comment: have you checked gson?

Comment: Use a JSON library... For instance [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind).

Comment: What ever ur requirement don't matter... any way you need to use anyone of the JSON api (Gson,jackson,etc,..) because you are going to convert json notation to object.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with:-

```
JSONSerializer.toJava(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [org.json.](http://www.json.org) Java parser.

```
public class RootImpl implements Root{
    private JSONObject root;

    public RootImpl(String json) {
        this.root = new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("ROOT");
    }

    public String getName(){
        return root.getString("NAME");
    }
}

Root root = new RootImpl("{\"ROOT\":{\"NAME\":\"EVEN\"}}");
System.out.println(root.getName()); // prints: EVEN
```

***References**:*
[JSON Java API docs](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Google GSON can help you !

"Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert a Java object into its 
JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string into an 
equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including 
pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of."  --Google-Gson 'README'

Download url:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

code example:

```
 //UserInfo object to json string
 public String toJson(UserInfo userInfo){
    //com.google.gson.Gson
    return new Gson().toJson(userInfo);
 }

 //json string to UserInfo object
 public UserInfo fromJson(String jsonStr){
     return new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, UserInfo.class);
 }
```